# Obtain distribution of mid-range in uniform

Tags: integration, statistics, education, uniform-distribution, order-statistics

I want to obtain distribution of mid-range, $(x_{(1)} + x_{(n)})/2$, of an uniform(a, b) random variable.  One can use the following transformation.

$M = \frac{X_{(1)} + X_{(n)}}{2}$ and $W = \frac{X_{(n)} - X_{(1)}}{2}$

clearly

$X_{(1)} = M-W$, $X_{(n)} = M + W$ and the jacobian is 2.

The joint distribution of $m, w$ is

$f(m, w) = 2^{n-1}n(n-1)w^{n-2}/(b-a)^n$.

Now i want to integrating with respect to $w$ to find distribution of mid-range. But i cannot determine the limit of $w$.  How should determine the limit of that?

Comment: I know that $0 < w < \frac{b-a}{2} - |m - \frac{a+b}{2}|$. But how find that is my problem

Comment: Special case: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/943696/321264.