# Distribution of the mean of max and min

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

Suppose $X_1,X_2,\cdots,X_n$ are iid uniform random variables on $[a,b]$, what is the distribution of $$Y_n=\frac{\max_{1\le i\le n}X_i+\min_{1\le i\le n}X_i}{2}?$$

Comment: Asked before at https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1106193/321264 but without answers. For $a=0$, you can see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/943696/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: I think the linear transformation from $[a,b]$ to $[0,c]$ is trivial enough that this can be closed as a duplicate.