# Order statistics excercise

Tags: probability, statistics

I have trouble solving this task:

Let $Y_1 < Y_2 < Y_3$ denote the order statistics of a random sample of size
3 from a distribution with pdf $f(x) = 1$, $0 < x < 1$, zero elsewhere. Let $$Z =
\frac{(Y_1 + Y_3)}{2}$$ be the midrange of the sample. Find the pdf of $Z$.

---

So far I have got this:

Joint pdf of $Y_1, Y_3$ is : $$f_{Y_1, Y_3}(y_1, y_3) = 6\ f(y_1) (F(y_3) - F(y_1)) f(y_3) = 6\ (y_3 - y_1) $$

Now I take $Z = \frac{(Y_1 + Y_3)}{2}$ and $R = Y_1$. 
$$Y_1 = R\\Y_3 = 2Z - R$$
Jacobian of this is $|J| = 2$. Thus joint pdf of $Z, R$ is: $$f_{Z, R}(z, r) = 6\ (2z - 2r) *|J| = 24(z-r)$$
I know that $Y_1 < Y_3$, so $R<2Z-R$, so $R<Z$. Now I want to compute integral:
$$\int_0^t \int_0^z 24(z-r)\ dr\ dz$$ to get cdf of $Z$. Now the problem is, that $z \in (0,1)$ and $$\int_0^t \int_0^z 24(z-r)\ dr\ dz = 4t^3$$
That would mean cdf $F_Z(1) = 4$ and it should be equal $1$ there.

Comment: Use $f_Z(z)\propto \int_0^z 2x\,dx= z^2$ for $z\in[0,\frac 1 2]$.

Comment: A general version: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/943696/321264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want to integrate over $z$.   This is the argument for your density function.   Just integrate out $r$.

You need to reconsider the bounds for this integral over $r$, so they don't exceed the support of the joint density function.

---

You have: $f_{\lower{0.5ex}{Y_1,Y_3}}(y_1,y_3) = 6(y_3-y_1) \;\mathbf 1_{0\leq y_1<y_3\leq 1}$

Then by using convolution and density scaling:

> $$\begin{align}f_Z(z) & = 2 \int_\Bbb R f_{Y_1,Y_3}(t,2z-t)\operatorname d t \\[1ex] & = 12\int_\Bbb R(2z-2t) \mathbf 1_{0\leq t<2z-t\leq 1}\operatorname d t \\[1ex] &= 24\int_{\max(0,2z-1)}^{\min(1,z)} (z-t)\operatorname d t\;\mathbf 1_{0\leq z\leq 1}\\[1ex] & = 24\int_{0}^{z}(z-t)\operatorname d t\,\mathbf 1_{0\leq z < 1/2}+24\int_{2z-1}^{z}(z-t)\operatorname d t\,\mathbf 1_{1/2\leq z \leq 1}\\[1ex] & = 12 z^2\;\mathbf 1_{0\leq z< 1/2}+ 12(z-1)^2\;\mathbf 1_{1/2\leq z\leq 1}\end{align}$$

Comment: Yeah, what You are doing is calculation of the distribution. Don't know why, but I wanted to get cdf and then differentiate to get pdf. But still, could You point me out where is the error in my calculations of cdf?

Comment: I guess I found the error. It is that interval for R was calculated wrongly. Thanks for the help.