# Probability Density Function of the Midrange of a Random Sample of Size 3 from a Uniform Distribution (0,1)

Tags: probability, statistics

[image]

I defined another random variable $W = \frac{Y_3-Y_1}{2}$, then we get $Y_1 = Z-W$ and $Y_3 = Z+W$. I then used the change of variables method and get the joint pdf of $Z$ and $W$ is $h_{W,Z}(w,z) = 24w$, but I do not think this is correct since when I integrate everything out I do not get $1$.

Comment: I think I know how to do the cdf method but in this problem we would require 4 integrals for it because of the support of $X$ so I wanted to know if the transformation method is a bit more tamed.

Comment: What 4 integrals? In the linked post, a transformation is made from $(Y_1,Y_3)\to (Y_3-Y_1,\frac12(Y_1+Y_3))$ and pdf of $\frac12(Y_1+Y_3)$ is derived as a marginal.

Comment: I did it without a transformation, I used the cdf without any transformations and just worked out the integrals and the bounds make it so that we choose a minimum of 2 variables in the lower bound and another 2 in the upper bound.

Answer (score -1):

**Comment:** Perhaps find beta distributions of max and min. Then distribution of their difference. This is precisely the approach of @StubbornAtom's useful link. Suggest looking carefully at that--even though your alternative method may work.

Sometimes, it helps to have a clear mental picture of the result. Below, the result is suggested by simulation in R, where `range` provides min and max (not their difference).

It may be worthwhile to notice that the standard deviation of the midrange of three observations is about $0.158,$ whereas the SD of their sample mean is larger:
$\sqrt{1/36} = 1/6 = 0.167.$ Thus, ***the midrange is a better estimator of the population mean than is the sample mean.***

```
set.seed(2020)
mr = replicate(10^5, mean(range(runif(3))))
sd(mr)
[1] 0.1580891
hist(mr, prob=T, br=50, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]